# Divide classes for variables

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I am trying to model the number of accidents from the age of the driver by GLM (for example: GLM Poisson). One thing that I see in many documents is that they divide the age by band, for example: [18, 25), [25, 50)... (so that the age will be treated like a categorical variable).

My question is that: do we have any technique/criteria to divide the age by band? 
(I've seen someone divide the band by the quantile of age, but I'm not sure about its  validity)

Answer (score 0):

This is substantive as much as statistical. From general knowledge it is clear that the relationship between accidents and age is sufficiently complicated to make e.g. linear or even low-order polynomials at best a crude summary. Young drivers can be reckless or inexperienced, and perhaps more likely to get drunk or to get involved in car chases by police. Much older drivers can have slower reflexes or are more likely to get sudden health problems while driving.

Depending on how large your sample is you might try some kind of scatterplot smoothing to get an idea of the relationship, but other covariates will interfere.

I am assuming that there is detailed literature on this, but I don't know what it is.